# skipping first row of a html table Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, web

I am still learning xpath and I am trying to skip the first row of a table because the first row has no values. I am not having success i searched through stack over flow and could not find anyone with a similar issue. My code is below:

```
int reqIndex = 0;

        do {

        List<WebElement> payDates = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[starts-with(@id,'changeStartWeekGrid_row_')]/td[contains(@id,'_cell_4')/span]"));
        System.out.println(payDates);

                for(WebElement pd:payDates) {                           
                LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
                java.util.Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(localDate.toString());

                  String str = pd.getText();

                  if ( str >= (d) ){ // still figuring this out
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath( "//tr[@id='changeStartWeekGrid_row_'" + reqIndex +"])/TBODY[@id='changeStartWeekGrid_rows_tbody']/TR[7]/TD[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]")).click();
                    break;
                    }else{
                         reqIndex++;
                        }

                        }
                    }while(reqIndex < 7 ); /// do this 7 times

                Thread.sleep(10000);
```

This is the part i am trouble shooting right now

```
List<WebElement> payDates = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[starts-with(@id,'changeStartWeekGrid_row_')]/td[contains(@id,'_cell_4')/span]"));
                    System.out.println(payDates);
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
```

The xpath works the problem is that it is selecting the first row and it has no values row zero does so it needs to skip the first row and go to row zero.
when i run the code i get this message:

```
( //tr[starts-with(@id,'changeStartWeekGrid_row_')]/td[contains(@id,'_cell_4')/span])
ilter expression must evaluate to nodeset.
```

the row highlighted is the row i am trying to skip
[image]

cell 4 image

[image]

-----radio button html code below

```
<div id="changeStartWeekGrid.store.rows[5].cells[0]_widget" tabindex="0" class="revitRadioButton dijitRadio" onfocus="var registry = require('dijit/registry'); registry.byId('changeStartWeekGrid').changeActiveCell('changeStartWeekGrid_row_5_cell_0', event);" onblur="var registry = require('dijit/registry'); registry.byId('changeStartWeekGrid').blurActiveCell('changeStartWeekGrid.store.rows[5]', 'changeStartWeekGrid.store.rows[5].cells[0]');"><div class="revitRadioButtonIcon"></div></div>
```

---radio button picture

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also use

```
//tr[starts-with(@id,'changeStartWeekGrid_row_') and not(starts-with(@id, 'changeStartWeekGrid_row_column'))]/td[5]/span
```

Comment: I get this message (selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //tr[starts-with(@id,'changeStartWeekGrid_row_') and not(starts-with(@id, 'changeStartWeekGrid_row_column'))]/td[contains(@id,'_cell_4')/span] because of the following error:
Error: Filter expression must evaluate to nodeset.)

Comment: I've just added some filter to your xpath. May be the last part is wrong. Give us plain HTML.

Comment: Yes the last filter `[contains(@id,'_cell_4')/span]` is definitely wrong. Corrected

Answer (score 2):

Try to use XPath

```
//table[@id='changeStartWeekGrid_rows_table']//tr[preceding-sibling::tr]
```

to select all `tr` nodes except the firts one

You can also use [`position()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/position) as below:

```
//table[@id='changeStartWeekGrid_rows_table']//tr[position()>1]
```

Note that in XPath indexation starts from `1` and so `[position()>1]` predicate means *return all sibling nodes skiping the first one*

Comment: what about /td[contains(@id,'_cell_4')/span]

Comment: I see no such elements on provided image. Update your question with HTML as plain text if you want improved solution. Also add some clarification as according to current description and title you just want to skip first `tr`

Comment: The updated image is posted above.. and yes i do want to skip the 1st tr or table row but after that i need to get/ print off the values of all the calendar dates in cell 4 of every row

Comment: Give us not image but html in plain text. And the target cell is not 4th but 5th

Comment: @Jonathan , if you want to get every 4-th `td` from each `tr` except the first one - `//table[@id='changeStartWeekGrid_rows_table']//tr[position()>1]/td[position()=4]`

Comment: yes i am trying to get the 4th td table data from each tr table row.. i will try this

Comment: correction *** yes i am trying to get the 5th td table data from each tr table row.. i will try this

Comment: For 5th node - `//table[@id='changeStartWeekGrid_rows_table']//tr[position()>1]/td[position()=5]`

Comment: Okay that worked and the one before this worked as well. My only problem i am having now is the if stament if ( str >= (d) ) i get a red line in eclipse

Comment: There both string so i am thinking >= should work? right

Comment: My goal here is to click on the radio button that corresponds the date if it is grater than or equal the current date

Comment: Oh, I'm afraid I won't help you as I'm not a Java coder

Comment: no problem thanks for your help it has worked so far .. i posted one more thing the radio button basically i want to link the radio button to the cell that has the correct date i posted the radio button html above

Comment: basically how would i write the xpath to click the radio button that corresponds to the date that is selected?

Comment: The one provided on picture doesn't really looks like a radio button...Usually it should be `<input type="radio">`... Can you share page URL?

Comment: @Andersson Just getting this message now about sharing page url I will do that in the morning.